# What do the tags mean for Windows Docker images?

Tags: windows, docker

There are lots of different tags available for Windows base images ([Nano Server](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-nanoserver), [Server Core](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-servercore), etc.). Is there any documentation for what the tag names mean? I've only been able to find an explanation for LTSC ([Long Term Service Channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/servicing-channels-comparison)). For example, what does the tag "1809" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tags for Windows Docker images refer to the version of Windows they are based on. The tag "1809" refers to Windows 10, version 1809. Each tagged image has a different servicing lifecycle, which is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/base-image-lifecycle).